# Can I add AWS Name Servers with my existing Name Servers to my registrar to create additional public records via AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, dyndns

I currently have my domains registered and managing DNS with DynDNS.

I'm looking to deploy machines to AWS and spin up DNS records based off their hostnames in AWS, but I'm having problems with Dyn's API and haven't been able to successfully do this.

I don't want to transfer over all of my DynDNS zones and export/import my records to AWS.

Is it possible to **create NS records in Dyn** that would **add the AWS NS values** so that whatever records I create within AWS underneath those NS's are then able to propagate normally via Dyn?

I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I need to elaborate more.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it's probably possible. You could write a lambda function and associate it somehow with changes, perhaps via SNS. You really would be better off using Route 53, it's all well integrated and supports very low TTL values.

Answer (score 1):

You could delegate a subzone.  So for "example": `aws.example.com` would be for your AWS instances while dyn would continue to serve `example.com`.  Then new hosts in AWS would look like `foo.aws.example.com` and `bar.aws.example.com`.  To make this work:

1. Create and test the subzone on AWS with a zone file like:

   ```
   ; zone fragment for sub-domain aws.example.com
   ; name servers in the same zone
   $TTL 2d ; default TTL = 2 days
   $ORIGIN aws.example.com.
   @              IN     SOA   ns3.aws.example.com. hostmaster.aws.example.com. (
                  2003080800 ; serial number
                  2h         ; refresh =  2 hours
                  15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
                  3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
                  2h20M      ; minimum = 2 hours + 20 minutes
                  )
   ; sub-domain name servers
                     IN      NS     ns1.aws.example.com.
                     IN      NS     ns2.aws.example.com.
   ; sub-domain mail server
                     IN      MX 10  mail.aws.example.com.
   ; A records for name servers above 
   ns1               IN      A      10.10.0.24
   ns2               IN      A      10.10.10.24

   ; A record for mail server above 
   mail              IN      A      10.10.0.25
   ```
2. Delegate to those name servers in your `example.com` zone at Dyn:

   ```
   aws.example.com.      IN     NS     ns1.aws.example.com.
   aws.example.com.      IN     NS     ns2.aws.example.com.
   ns1.aws.example.com.  IN     A      10.10.0.24
   ns2.aws.example.com.  IN     A      10.10.10.24
   ```

   **Note**: You need the `NS` and `A` records in both the subzone and superzone zone files for this to work.
3. Increment the serial number in your `example.com` zone.  Reload and test.

For more check out [this tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html).

Comment: @user391602 is this working for you?